# Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

Installed the **Google App Engine SDK.Python 2.7** perfect.

Wanted to go into images, and test locally.Installed PIL

But trying to do localhost image manipulation gives:

```
"NotImplementedError: Unable to find the Python PIL library. Please view the SDK documentation for details about installing PIL on your system."
```

Again it threw with this **error message**

```
Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: A bit vague. Post your app.yaml file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roger. But I was worried about touching app.yaml file. 
But downloading Pillow for 64bit helped me working out.